# Use ID as a cursor to page over documents in a Firestore collection

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

How can I use the ID of a document as a cursor to iterate through a collection server-side (i.e., using the Firebase Java Admin SDK)?

Iterating over the documents in order of (random) ID is fine (the actual order is unimportant for now), I just want to iterate over every document. Want to avoid having to waste a field to store the ID in the document itself.

I tried the following code:

```
String lastId = null;
do {
    Query q = collectionRef.limit(100);
    if (null != lastId) {
        q = q.startAfter(lastId);
    }
    snapshots = q.get().get().getDocuments();
    if (Lists.isNotEmpty(snapshots)) {
        lastId = snapshots.get(snapshots.size() - 1).getId();
    }
} while (Lists.isNotEmpty(snapshots));
```

where `Lists.isNotEmpty(List<?>)` is a convenience method that also checks for null references.

This resulted in:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Too many cursor values specified. The specified values must match the orderBy() constraints of the query.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:507)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.Query.createCursor(Query.java:339)
    at com.google.cloud.firestore.Query.startAfter(Query.java:797)
```

This implies that I need to have an `orderBy(idFieldName)` clause in the query.

Is there a special (reserved) name for the (hidden?) ID property of a document?

For reasons of my own I don't want to use a whole DocumentSnapshot as the cursor value and I would prefer to not have to use/create any other property to `orderBy()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pagination in Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) requires that you either:

1. Define the order of results so that the pages of data are predictable.  You need to either specify a startAt/startAfter value to indicate where in the ordering to begin receiving ordered documents.
2. Use a document snapshot to indicate the next document to receive.

You can either put the document ID into the document itself and order on it, or you can use [FieldPath.documentId()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldPath.html#documentId()) to order by the ID without having to add one.  This lets you implement option 1.

Comment: Does the field that is used to orderBy have to have unique values for most (if not all) documents? If not, how would Firestore know at which document exactly to resume when paging is used?

Comment: You can't sort or index on anything that's null.  Values must be present to be indexed, and therefore queryable at scale.

Comment: What about noon-unique values (I changed my comment)?

Comment: You could have a problem if your field is not unique and your page cuts off between documents that have the same value.  Your sort field should be unique, which it will be if you use the document id.

Comment: Ah! Rings within rings! Thanks for the help.

Comment: There actually is a "hidden" documentId field that you can order by.  You just do `.orderBy(FieldPath.documentId())` https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldPath.html#documentId()

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer Wow, that really needs to be elevated in the documentation, because I *always* forget about that! :-)

Comment: i'm not able to orderBy(FieldPath.documentId()), i get The corresponding value for FieldPath.documentId() must be a String or a DocumentReference, 
How can i implement it correctly ?